# Foreach Loop does not insert all records from quickbooks to MySQL database.

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, sql-insert, quickbooks-online

I been working on Quickbooks PHP API and I wanted to get data from quickbooks and save in MYSQL using PHP script.

I have successfully connected Quickbooks with PHP and I have done queries to get the data.

```
  $Products = $ProductsService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM item ");
foreach ($Products as $Product)
 {
    //First, we will retrieve the ID, and strip out any spaces/characters.  
    $id = $Product->getId();
    $ProductID = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$id);

    echo('Customer Id=' . $ProductID. '<br>');


    //// test for product name
    if(!empty($Product->getName())){
        $ProductName = $Product->getName();
    } else {
        $ProductName= '';
    }

    //Insert customer into product tables
    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (ProductID__kp, ProductName) 

        VALUES ('".$ProductID."', 
                '".$ProductName."'

                )
                ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                    UPDATE ProductName = '".$ProductName."' ";

    $conn->query($sql);

}
```

The above script successfully runs and returns result in arrays.

[image]

The problems is insert statement. I have 1579 products in quickbooks. But when I run the above script, only 97 records gets saved in MYSQL database.

I'm not sure why it only saves 97 out of 1579.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you posting screenshots of code/responses instead of actual code/responses?

You are actively making it more difficult for us to answer, by taking screenshots of the response instead of just copy/pasting. You're also making extra work for yourself. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have two unrelated problems here:

**The QuickBooks Online APIs only return 100 records at a time by default.**

Read the documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0300_references/0000_programming_guide/0050_data_queries

You're only getting back 100 records. You can tell by the size of the array:

`array(100)`

**You're ignoring any error checking at all.**

`$conn->query($sql);`

Why don't you watch for and catch any errors that happen?

Then you'd know if a query was failing or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Quickbooks documentation, it will return 100 records if you run this

```
$Products = $ProductsService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM item");
```

Instead, you can make use of the `MAXRESULTS`. You can take a look at the below line of code.

```
$Products = $ProductsService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM item MAXRESULTS 9999");
```